# Calculate the Upper Divmod

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory, division

## Task

Given two positive integers (divid**e**nd and divis**o**r), calculate the **q**uotient and the **r**emainder.
Normally it would be calculated as `e = o*q+r` where `q*o<=e` and `0<=r<o`.
For this challenge it still `e = o*q+r` but `q*o>=e` and `-o<r<=0`.
For example `e=20` and `o=3`, normally it would be `20/3 -> 20=3*6+2`, since `18<=20` and `0<=2<3`. Here it will be `20/3 -> 20=3*7-1` where `21>=20` and `-3<-1<=0`

## Test Cases

```
Input -> Output
20, 3 -> 7, -1
10, 5 -> 2, 0
7, 20 -> 1, -13
100, 13 -> 8, -4
```

You don't need to handle `o=0`.

Comment: Called it on being a trivial variant of regular divmod.

Comment: Is it acceptable to output `r` as the negation of the real `r` for languages that uses unsigned bytes to store data or assume overflowing? (`-1` → `1` / `255`)

Comment: @Uriel yes, but add a note about this on the answer

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <strike>39</strike> 26 bytes

[Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) saved 13 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:(-(x//-y),x%-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9JKQ1ejQl9ft1JTp0IVSP4vKMrMK9FI0zAy0DHW1FRQVjDXUdA15IIJGxromIKFjXQUDOCi5jpGBmBRQ5BiYyTVBjqGEGMsgDIm/wE)

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:(-(x/-y),x%-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9JKQ1ejQl@3UlOnQhVI/i8oyswr0UjTMDLQMdbUVFBWMNdR0DXkggkbGuiYgoWNdBQM4KLmOkYGYFFDkGJjJNUGOoYQYyyAMib/AQ)

Comment: I think you can just do `x%-y` to get the remainder.

Comment: Actually, why not go all the way... `(-(x//-y),x%-y)`

Comment: @MartinEnder Thats really good

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Included both

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
NdN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98vxe/////m/40MAA)

#### How it works

Abusing divmod again \o/. Look ma’ no unicode!

```
NdN - Full program / Dyadic chain. | Example: 7, 20

N   - Negate the first input.      | -7
 d  - Divmod by the second one.    | [-1, 13]
  N - Negate each again.           | [1, -13]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
n#k=[-div(-n)k,mod n(-k)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0852zZaNyWzTEM3TzNbJzc/RSFPQzdbM/Z/bmJmnoKtQko@lwIQFBRl5pUoqCgYGSgoKxijCBmChExRhMyBIkYGaKpAygyN/wMA)

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
{s=⌈#/#2⌉,#-#2s}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v7rY9lFPh7K@stGjnk4dZV1lo@Jatf8BRZl5JQ5p0UYGOsaxXDCeoYGOKYJnrmNkgCxnoGNoHPsfAA)

Comment: Can you add an explanation, please?

Comment: @Rod `⌈#/#2⌉` calculates the ceiling of their division, and stores it in a variable `s`, and then subtracts argument 2 * s from argument 1.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder you are fast!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
(s‰(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fo/hRwwaN//8NDQy4DI0B)

**5 bytes**

```
(‰ćÄJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f41HDhiPth1u8/v83NOYyNDAAAA)

#### How they work

Abuses Python's modulo! \o/

```
(s‰(  | Full program. Let A and B be the two inputs. | Example: 100, 13.

(     | Compute -A.                                  | -100
 s    | Swap (reverse the stack, in this case).      | 13, -100
  ‰   | Divmod.                                      | [-8, 4]
   (  | Negative (multiply each by -1, basically).   | [8, -4]

----------------------------------------------------

(‰ćÄJ | Full program. Takes input in reverse order.

(     | Negative. Push -A.
 ‰    | Divmod
  ć   | Push head extracted divmod (make the stack [quotient, [remainder]].
   Ä  | Absolute value (operates on the quotient).
    J | Join the stack.
```

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that the divmod works with negative numbers :)

Comment: And also, that's new functionality of `J` isn't it?. Never seen that before. Could definitely be useful.

Comment: @Emigna It is described as *Join. Push ''.join(a) if a is list; Else, push ''.join(stack)*. I think it is the new functionality, although I haven't ever used `J` before :P

Comment: It's definitely new. Tried on my local version from August and `5)6` gives `['5']6` :)

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/O.
\io/R%e,R:R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fX48rJjNfP0g1VSfIKuj/fyMDLmMA)

#### Explanation

Ruby's integer division and modulo (on which Alice's are implemented) are defined such that using a negative divisor already sort of does what we want. If we negated the divisor we automatically get the correct modulo, and we get minus the quotient we want. So the easiest way to solve this is by negating a bunch of numbers:

```
/   Switch to Ordinal mode.
i   Read all input as a string "e o".
.   Duplicate the string.
/   Switch to Cardinal mode.
R   Implicitly convert the top string to the two integer values it
    contains and negate o.
%   Compute e%-o.
e,  Swap the remainder with the other copy of the input string. We can't
    use the usual ~ for swapping because that would convert the string 
    to the two numbers first and we'd swap e%-o in between e and o instead
    of to the bottom of the string.
R   Negate o again.
:   Compute e/-o.
R   Negate the result again.
\   Switch to Ordinal mode.
O   Output -(e/-o) with a trailing linefeed.
o   Output e%-o.

    The code now bounces through the code for a while, not doing much except
    printing a trailing linefeed when hitting O again. Eventually, the IP
    reaches : and attempts a division by zero which terminates the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 18 bytes

```
x->y->-[-x\y,-x%y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7v0LXrlLXTjdatyKmUke3QrUy9n9BUWZeiUaahpGBpoaxpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
_&\_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P14tJv7/f0NjLkMDAwA)

*-1 byte thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)*

```
      # implicit input
_     # unary minus (negates first input, o)
&\    # alternative output mod, returns remainder, quotient, implicitly takes e
_     # unary minus, takes the opposite of the quotient.
      # implicit output, prints stack as remainder
                                         quotient
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 18 bytes

```julia
x$y=.-fldmod(-x,y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/QqXSVk83LSclNz9FQ7dCp1Lzf0FRZl5JTp6GkYGKsSYXjGdooGKK4JmrGBkgyxmoGBpr/gcA)

`.-` is element wise negation, and `fldmod` returns a tuple made of the results of floored divison and corresponding residue.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>37</s> <s>31</s> <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Rod*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

Takes input in currying syntax. Returns **[q,r]**.

```js
a=>b=>[q=~-a/b+1|0,a-q*b]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>b=>[q=~-a/b+1|0,a-q*b]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(20)(3)))   // -> 7, -1
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(10)(5)))   // -> 2, 0
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(7)(20)))   // -> 1, -13
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(100)(13))) // -> 8, -4
```

Comment: You can probably `q=(a+b-1)/b+|0` instead `q=a/b+.9|0`

Comment: @ETHproductions Sounds like a plan. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
([-]*a),~a=.>.@%
```

This is essentially the Jenny_mathy's Mathematica solution rewritten in J.

## How it works:

`a=.>.@%` Finds the ceiling of the division of the left and right arguments and stores it into variable a

`,~`  concatenated to (reversed)

`([-]*a)` subtracts a*right argument from the left argument

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F8jWjdWK1FTpy7RVs9Oz0H1vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvoKRgUKagjGEbQhim0LY5kCmkQFMHCRhaPwfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(e,o)-c(e%/%-o,-e%%o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jVSdfUzdZI1VVX1U3X0c3VVU1X/N/moaRgY6xJleahqGBjimINtcxMoDwDXQMjTX/AwA)

Comment: I think you can do a 29 byter with `-c(e%/%-o,-e%%o)`

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 7 bytes

Built-in function `ceiling` returns two values: the ceiling of the quotient, and the remainder to match:

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (ceiling 20 7)
3 ;
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), <s>55</s> 50 bytes

```
3.711712114001231311141130013513213131211513115154
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYm5EYAwDARzVSFSZvD49NhDQNEkpA7cCY0ImWjvdi1CSwc6BLBaIQpFTkDzqUMFS2X2VRxuEe9zz0GU4IOBdnaaI6e4U0laoy2hSvRXvlbiPcOvPw)

Represents the reminder by it's negation (`10` instead of `-10`), since the language uses byte input and output, deemed valid by OP comment.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 + 1 (`-p`) = 31 bytes

```perl
say+($_-($\=$_%-($"=<>)))/$"}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJbQyVeV0MlxlYlXhVIK9na2GlqauqrKNVW//9vZMBl/C@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BocF/3QIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), 90 bytes

```
//
;{- -}
{-{-//-}e#<!-}
;{-{-{- -}-}-}
{-{-{-e#-}
;{-{- -}-}
{-%e#*/-}#          /*-}e#*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU3NK0ksyS/6/19fn8u6WldBt5arWrdaV19ftzZV2UYRyLUG8cEyIMgF4aUqw2QUoKKqqcpaQE3KCnCgrwUyQ0v/////Rgb/jQE)

Outputs the remainder, then the quotient, newline separated.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
f(x,y,z)int*x;{for(z=0;*x>0;*x-=y)z++;y=z;}
```

### Usage

```c
main(){
    int a=7,b=20,c; 
    c=f(&a,b); 
    printf("%d %d\n",c,a);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoMwEAC/EgRlV1eIeFy2L@klrqR4aBTxkET69jRe5jIzOn5US/EQKVHGLVx95NvvJ2Sx3MfXg1ES5mHgJJl/5eu2AHjX1DiZrKVFppmUjYqHztGCbI6zag9Nu5p2fYeGlBzW9w8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 30 bytes

```java
(i,j)->(i+j-1)/j+","+(i%j-j)%j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xD4IwEIV3fsWFhKQNLQLGOBDdHZxYSIxDhUpaoRAoBGP47VgRR3W45C7vvfueZD2jVc2VzG5TWrC2hSMT6mEBCKV5c2Uph@R1AsS6ESqHAR2MkvMGGIHPesGR8YxmWs20SCGBAXYwIUEkpnskXEkDvJKuTWwXCUdSiR05RZZJ1N2lMIkl2Fcig9J0QG/e6QwMzwXie6t56VWd9mqj6EKhwRtQ6JM1nvHfHIFPNr8dWxL6/374JFg4ozVOTw)

```java
7,-1
2,0
1,-13
8,-4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 35 bytes

```
L*,@0$_$2D2D%V/1B]b\GLVB]-1Gx$pBcB*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HS8fBQCVexcjFyEU1TN/QKTYpxt0nzClW19C9QqXAKdlJ6////@b/jQwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 23 bytes

```
@l0-%z]@l0-,l0-@l0-miE_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f/fIcdAV7UqFkTpADGIzs10jf///7/5fyMDAA)

### How it works

```
@                       - Swap the inputs
 l0-                    - Negate
    %                   - Modulo
     z]                 - Push the inputs
       @                - Swap
        l0-             - Negate
           ,            - Integer divide
            l0-         - Negate
               @        - Swap
                l0-     - Negate
                   miE_ - Print
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc) 41 bytes

```
f(a,b){b=(a+b-1)/b;}g(a,b){b=a-f(a,b)*b;}
```

This may be cheating, using two functions and it may fail other tests?

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NU5LCsMgFNx7CgkEND6pJv0srCdJs9CEBBexJbgTz25tbRcDw3yYmfk2zzmvxICl0WpimOWSnqxK218zvNpdEfNunCc0IucDDqO8Tljj2AsYQAq4wA0Kl6JgSAqtz4N8gk4L5e5n5Rj7VU2phdF1/QRWfwmTk0Kvo5gradoFt8vDN1CXoX6hCiWU8hs)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>124</s> <s>123</s> 105 bytes

```
 E =INPUT
 O =INPUT
 Q =E / O
 R =E - Q * O
 EQ(0,R) :S(A)
 R =R - O
 Q =Q + 1
A OUTPUT =Q
 OUTPUT =R
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X8FVwdbTLyA0hEvBH84KVLB1VdBX8OdSCAKxdIECWiCea6CGgU6QpoJVsIajJlgyCCjpD9YQqKCtYMjlqOAfGgI0A8jngjODuFz9XP7/NzTgMgUA)

Takes input as `E`, then `O`, separated by a newline and prints out `Q`, then `R`, separated by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 47 bytes

```swift
func f(a:Int,b:Int){print((a+b-1)/b,(a%b-b)%b)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TXR: 8 bytes

Built-in function `ceil-rem`. E.g. `(ceil-rem 20 7)` yields `(7 -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 42 bytes

```
import StdEnv
f a b#c=(a-1)/b+1
=(c,a-c*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcq7DkAwFADQ3VfcxOLVeCymbgwSmy@4vVSatCWUxM@7nPmQXdCz2@bLLuDQeDZu344AU5h7f0caEFRMMkFRp6XK60gmVKCgTKU8BfynBA0tNBW/pC2uJ4th5O7x6AydHw)